# Question about taylor expansion

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

If I was given a function which its derivative is bounded for every $x>0$ (means: $|f'(x)|\le M$), How can I prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}=0$?

Comment: $ f'(x) \le M $ or $ f(x) \le M $?

Comment: l'hopital may come in handy. Also, I think you've written $|f(x)|\le M$ where you mean $|f'(x)|\le M$.

Comment: If $\lim_{ x \to \infty} f(x) =\infty$, then you can prove the result using Gerry Myerson's hint.

Comment: yes, if the limite was infinity, it was quiet easy, But I know nothing else about this

Comment: @theOrthanormalBeginner: So work out the problem as cases.

Comment: fine. cases (fix me if I'm worng) are:
a. limit=infinity- we activate l'hostpital bound it with 0 and M/2x and squeeze theorem to get limit=0
b. 0<limit<infinity, then the x^2 tends to infinty and the f(x) tends to soemthing positive. so it all tends to 0.
Do you think it's an acceptable solution?

Comment: In the second case, $f$ might not tend to a limit, but it is in any event bounded, which is more than enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use l'Hospital for this one, since it is annoying to deal with the case where we don't have $\lim_{+\infty} f=+\infty$, which is the usual assumption to apply it in this case.

By the mean value theorem, for all $x>1$, theres exists $1<c_x<x$ such that $f(x)-f(1)=f'(c_x)(x-1)$. It follows that
$$
|f(x)-f(1)|\leq M|x-1|\qquad\forall x>1.
$$
By triangular inequality, $|f(x)|=|f(x)-f(1)-f(1)|\leq |f(x)-f(1)|+|f(1)|$ and $|x-1|\leq |x|+1=x+1$ for all $x>1$, so
$$
|f(x)|\leq |f(1)|+M+Mx=C+Mx \qquad \forall x>1.
$$
Hence
$$
0\leq \frac{|f(x)|}{x^2}\leq \frac{C+Mx}{x^2}\qquad\forall x>1.
$$
Now the rhs tends to $0$ as $x$ tends to $+\infty$, so the result follows by squeezing.

Answer (score 2):

If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)<\infty$, the result holds.

Otherwise, use L'H rule. Since $f'(x)$ is bounded while $x$ is not bounded, you get the result.

Comment: if the limit in infinity<infinity, that can everything (even e). I can't know whether the limit is infinite or not...

Comment: The denominator goes to infinity, what would a finite number divides infinity be?

Comment: I think you should make your alternative clearer. Note that $\lim f<\infty$ is not the opposite of $\lim f=+\infty$.